# Surface Laptop Keyboard Kernel Installation Error

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, kernel, keyboard

```
root@O22UGDW213:~# apt update

E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian/ release: /var/lib/extrepo/keys/surface-linux.asc != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.

root@O22UGDW213:~# sudo add-apt-repository --remove https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian/
Repository: 'deb https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian/ jammy main'
Description:
Archive for codename: jammy components: main
More info: https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian/
Removing repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://pkg.surfacelinux.com/debian/ release: /var/lib/extrepo/keys/surface-linux.asc != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```